# Unique in order C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have some trouble with executing an exercise from CodeWars. I made it in another compilator and everything works as it has to be but in CodeWars there are IEnumerable errors and I have no idea how to deal with them.

So, here is the exercise:

> Implement the function `unique_in_order` which takes as argument a
> sequence and returns a list of items without any elements with the
> same value next to each other and preserving the original order of
> elements.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> uniqueInOrder("AAAABBBCCDAABBB") == {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B'}
> uniqueInOrder("ABBCcAD")         == {'A', 'B', 'C', 'c', 'A', 'D'}
> uniqueInOrder([1,2,2,3,3])       == {1,2,3}
> ```

---

My solution:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Kata {
    public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) {

    var first = iterable[0];
    
    var uniques = new List<char>();

    uniques.Add(first);
    
    foreach(var item in iterable)
    {
        if (item == first)
        {
            continue;
        }
        first = item;
        uniques.Add(first);
    }

    var result = string.Join("", uniques);

   return result;
  }
}
```

Errors I get:

> src/Solution.cs(8,17): error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<T>'
> src/Solution.cs(26,12): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'

Comment: Can't make it a List<char> (Or a return type of string) if you want it to work on arrays of ints. Use a List<T> and return it

Comment: `var first = iterable[0];` - you can't index the first item in an enumerable like this. I'm surprised that works in your other compiler - which one? I think `T first = null;` (or `= default(T)`) and drop `uniques.Add(first);` would work fine.

Comment: Although depending how thorough the test cases are it might be simplest to use a 'first' boolean flag instead, or unpack the IEnumerable into an IEnumerator and use that to pop off the first item of the list. I also don't think your return string join is going to work correctly for both the int list and string cases. You might need a separate implementation for strings.

Comment: I get the feeling you are supposed to iterate `iterable` and `yield return` whatever T you find that is not the same as the previous T, unless you're taking the "and return a list of items" part literally

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `yield return` keyword? They're handy.

```
class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        T prev = default!;
        bool hasPrev = false;

        foreach (T item in sequence)
        {
            if ((!hasPrev && (hasPrev = true)) || !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, prev))
            {
                yield return item;
            }

            prev = item;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(UniqueInOrder("AAAABBBCCDAABBB").ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine(new string(UniqueInOrder("ABBCcAD").ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close to a solution. Let's run through some errors:

In this statement: `var first = iterable[0];` you can't access an IEnumerable item via indexing. IEnumerables aren't really lists or collections. I can expand on that if you'd like.

You could access it through:

```
var first = iterable.First();
```

In this statement:  `var uniques = new List<char>();`, you're creating a list of char to hold the itens of your IEnumerable, although the itens are of generic type `T`. The correct form is:

```
var uniques = new List<T>();
```

In the line `if (item == first)`, you can't compare two unconstrained generic types using `==`.

You can either use `item.Equals(first)` or `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, first)`.

Lastly, you're transforming your list in a string and returning it. Although the return type of your method is not a string, but rather an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Instead of

```
 var result = string.Join("", uniques);

 return result;
```

You can get rid of `result`, and return your list:

```
return uniques;
```

With these fixes, your code becomes:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) 
{
    var first = iterable.First();
    
    var uniques = new List<T>();

    uniques.Add(first);
    
    foreach(var item in iterable)
    {
        if (item.Equals(first))
        {
            continue;
        }
        first = item;
        uniques.Add(item);
    }

    return uniques;
}
```

Which already works. However, this code could be simplified by removing the assignment of the `first` variable and integrating it to a more general case. You could also remove the `uniques` list and yield each item at a time.

My proposed final solution is as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) 
{
    var current = default(T);
    
    foreach(var item in iterable)
    {
        if (item.Equals(current))
            continue;
            
        current = item;
        
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Last suggestion is one of the best practice , thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, exchange `var first = iterable[0];` with `var first = iterable.First()`.
You can't use indexing on `IEnumerable`.

Secondly you are using list of chars  `List<char>();` to store type `T`. Use `List<T>`.
You can't store general type as specific.

Thirdly, why you are using `String.Join()` at the end, why not just return uniques? 
`List` is also an `IEnumerable`.